# Issue with Docker Toolbox

Tags: docker, dockerhub, docker-toolbox

I have been getting the following problem after getting Docker set-up on a Mac OS using the Docker Toolbox:

```
Pulling repository docker.io/library/hello-world
Error while pulling image: Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/hello-world/images: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I have seen some potential solutions to this problem on StackOverflow, but none of them seems to be working for me. For example, I have checked the date, which is set correctly in my case. Does anyone know of a solution for the Docker Toolbox on a Mac OS X?

Comment: Maybe elaborate a bit on what you've tried so far?

Comment: I think this thread mentions both workarounds and fixes: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8849

Comment: @jangroth That solution appears to be dealing with a private registry, but I'm trying to pull from the public registry.

Comment: Are you trying to pull from inside a container? I'm wondering if the certs are missing. You might need to install them.